# Safari Bookmarklet - accessing DOM

Tags: safari

I've tried following bookmarklets:

> javascript:document.body.style.width='50%';

or

> javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].width='50%';

They both work in console, but not in bookmarklet. What is the reason?

They both work fine as Chrome's bookmarklets.

Also, this bookmarklet works fine (on HTML5 videos):

> javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate=2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari requires that a literal percent sign in a URL (`%`) be URL-encoded in a bookmarklet (`%25`...while it looks like that's just 25 added, the percent sign followed by two numbers is decoded to a literal percent sign). Also, the property is `.style.width`, not just `.width`.

Change your bookmarklet to this:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.width='50%25';
```

I've confirmed this works in Safari v8.0.6 (OS X 10.10.3).

Comment: Quick Google search!

Comment: But how? What did you search? I've spend ages on Google. The biggest frustration was that it worked in console.

Comment: I never got just `.width` working in console, which prompted me to add `.style`. As for my search, I think I used "Safari JavaScript bookmarklet" and it's the third result that led me down the URL encoding path.

Comment: The percent sign works in console because it's not reading it from a URL, obviously, so it doesn't expect the percent sign to be encoded there.

Comment: It does flash address bar for a second, although you can't execute JS from address bar in Safari.